# How to implement DropboxOAuth2Flow in node.js?

Tags: node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk, dropbox-sdk-js

In the [Dropbox markdown webhook example](https://github.com/dropbox/mdwebhook/blob/master/app.py), they used the `DropboxOAuth2Flow` from the Python SDK to link a Dropbox account to the Webhook app. I want to implement the same thing in Node.js and I couldn't find any thing similar in their JavaScript SDK documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example of using the OAuth flow in Node via the official Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/javascript/simple-backend/code_flow_example.js